# Angular 2 : Template driven form, pass object from selected element to submitting object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Hello I am new to Angular 2 and I'm searching for a good way to solve this from some time. So I have user object that contains another object inside. That user is an interface :

```
export interface userModel{
  name: string,
  service: Service
}
```

Got an array of services and form for creating new User.

```
<form #f="ngForm" (submit)="addUser(f.value,f.valid)">
    <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="userModel.name" #name="ngModel" name="name" ng-maxlength="49" />
    </div>
    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">Service</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="service" [(ngModel)]="userModel.service">
            <option *ngFor='let service of services' [value]='service'>{{service.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Create</button>
</form>
```

How can i pass selected service object to User object? When i fill it this way i get:

```
Object{
  "name": "something",
  "service": "[Object object]"
}
```

So obviously i can't pass object as value to select element.
Then i setted that value to id of Service instead.
Modified interface:

```
export interface UserModel{
   name: string,
   serviceId: number
}
```

And before submission i find Service object by that id in array of services and set it in User object with Service object inside.

```
userModel: UserModel;
user: User;

submit(model: UserModel ){
   this.user = {
     name : model.name,
     service: this.findService(model.serviceId) 
  }
}



ngOnInti(){
 this.userModel= <userModel>{};
}
```

Is this ok ? Is there better way to manage this? This is working example and just part of (handwriten) code. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It stored `[Object object]` because you have `value` attribute which do stringify the object. As you wanted to store Object value on option selection, you should use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`. Basically `[ngValue]` property persist & keep object value happy.

**Markup**

```
<select class="form-control" name="service" [(ngModel)]="userModel.service">
  <option *ngFor='let service of services' [ngValue]='service'>
     {{service.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: wow, that was fast...thx, just googled it and found "Since 2.0.0-beta.14 an object can be bound to <option> using ngValue", works nice, +1 and accepting answer